# Write down a map $f$ from the torus $T$ to itself such that the induced map $g:H_1(T) \to H_1(T)$ is given by the matrix ( 1 1 : 0 1)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I think $f(x,y)=(x,x+y)$.

suppose $f(x,y)=(x,x+y)$.then I am looking at the action of $g$ on the generators of $H_1(T)$. but I can't show that.

Answer (score 1):

The standard generators of $H_1(T)$ are the latitudinal and longitudinal circles. Call them

$\alpha=\{x,y\in [0,1]^2\mid x=0\}$ and

$\beta=\{x,y\in [0,1]^2\mid y=0\}$

and write an element $a[\alpha] + b[\beta]\in H_1(T)$ as $(a,b)$.

The matrix $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ then acts on $H_1(T)$ by $A(a,b)=(a+b,a)$ so $f_*([\alpha]) = [\alpha] + [\beta]$ and $f_*([\beta]) = [\alpha]$. In particular, if we want $f$ to be induced by a linear map, then when $x=0$, which is the case for $\alpha$, we want $f(0,y)=(y,y)$ and when $y=0$, which is the case for $\beta$, we want $f(x,0)=(0,x)$ so $f(x,y)=(y,x+y)$.